# Subtract two columns in two different tablix SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have two tablix in my report(SSRS 2005). I want to subtract from two different columns. I use the following :

```
=Math.Round(Sum(Fields!LY_Sales.Value, "Ds1"))-Math.Round(Sum(Fields!TY_Sales.Value, "Ds2"))
```

For display of the columns i use the following:

```
=Format(Math.Round(Sum(Fields!LY_Sales.Value)),"#,##")
=Format(Math.Round(Sum(Fields!TY_Sales.Value)),"#,##")
```

sample display value : 
seperate columns : LY_Sales - 40,240
                   TY_Sales - 86,983
Difference value :  -47406

this does not show the actual difference, there is slightly difference in the value. Also i want to remove '-' symbol if it's negative i just want to show the difference. How can i resolve this 
Can anyone help me to do this...

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: The difference seems to be elated to the `Format(Math.Round(...))`, what is the value of `Sum(Fields!LY_Sales.Value)` and `Sum(Fields!TY_Sales.Value)`

Comment: Sum(Fields!LY_Sales.Value) = 40240.41  and Sum(Fields!TY_Sales.Value) = 86983.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this does not show the actual difference, there is slightly difference
>   in the value.

I've done some testing and could not reproduce your issue.
If you are testing in BIDS, I would advise to delete the cache as this could be a potential root cause.

> Also i want to remove '-' symbol if it's negative i just want to show
>   the difference.

You can do this with the `Abs()` function, which returns the absolute value of your input.

Your original expression would become:

```
=Abs(Round(Sum(Fields!LY_Sales.Value, "Ds1"))-Round(Sum(Fields!TY_Sales.Value, "Ds2")))
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. now i remove '-' symbol with my diff. value. Can we use any other way for finding different between 2 columns of seperate data sets ?